# Prevent overfitting when decreasing model complexity is not possible

Tags: keras

I'm fairly new to machine learning and as an exercise for a more complicated task, I'm trying to do the following what I thought was a trivial task. Suppose as an input I have population density maps. These are 2D images with one layer, in which each pixel is the count of persons living in that area.
From that data, I'd like my model to "estimate" (in fact it would be possible to calculate the exact solution) the total number of persons living on that density map. Essentially, the task consists of just taking the sum of the 2D input.
I have tried many architectures and I found that the simpler the better. In fact a model containing no hidden layers performed best:

```
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten, Input

inputs = Input(shape=(225, 350, 1))
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(1)(x)
```

While this performs very well on the training data, it fares very poorly on the validation data. I know that this is a sign of overfitting, but how can I prevent overfitting given that is not possible to further decrease complexity of the model? Or would another approach / architecture be better altogether?
Note that I have performed the usual data pre-processing (normalising inputs and outputs).

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: Regularization is the thing that you are after. Most commonly dropout, l1 and l2 regularization. But I think you should be using something like random forest and skip neural networks for this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is this about trying to have the model learn the sum function? Because if it is you can always initialize the weights to be 1 and then make the entire model untrainable.
If all weights are one and the model has linear activations it will just compute the sum of your inputs. If its important to you to train the model to do this I would add a Dropout layer (?).

Your model is so simple it can be written down in closed form as it is $\sum_{i=0}^{255*350}w_i x_i$ and therefore I would just set the $w_i$ to be 1.

(In general initializing the weights to 1, the ideal solution, should make training very fast)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In this example, setting the kernel_initializer to one works perfectly fine. What bothers me, is that the model cannot find these weights by itself, even if I let it train for a long time. In another example I have several layers and I don't know the inital weights, so I'm a bit concerned that the model will just shoot in the wrong direction.